# Receber array method POST form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando receber um Form como array , mas não estou conseguindo manipular corretamente este array. Tenho 6 campos 3 campos ID e 3 campos text , tentei fazer assim mas sem sucesso. Mas ele percorre 6 vezes o array , e não 3 como deveria ser.

retorna assim.
--ID--1---
--nome-------ID--2---
--nome-------ID--3---
--nome-------ID-----
--nome--wwe-----ID-----
--nome--qwwqe-----ID-----
--nome--wqeeqw---

```
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][id]" >
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][id]" >
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][id]" >
                            <label>array</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][nome]" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][nome]" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="array[][nome]" >
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" name="salvar">
                                salvar
                            </button>
                            </form>
```

$teste = $_POST['array'];
mysqli_select_db($conn,"test");
foreach ($teste as $key1 => $value1) {
                echo "--ID--".$value1['id']."---";
                echo "
";
                    echo "--nome--".$value1['nome']."---";

`$query = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE excluidos SET
                    rev2_email = '$aux' WHERE rev1_nome = '".$value1['id']."';");`

}

Comment: Bruno, e se você inverter, no formulário, os campos? Ao invés disso: "array[][id]", colocar isso: "array[id][]". Provavelmente deverá revisar seu foreach também, pois o array criado é multidimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra forma de se fazer:

Mude `name="array[][id]"` para `name="arrayid[]"` e `name="array[][nome]"` para `name="arraynome[]"`, no PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['arrayid'];
$nome = $_POST['arraynome'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
    echo "| $id[$i] | $nome[$i] |<br>";
}
```

Comment: Vlw mano , funcionou